# Where do I see the tracking for Keyword of Email Activity in Journey?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder, analytics

When placing an email on the journey, we have in the advanced options the item "Add a Keyword". The documentation(https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_configure_the_send_email_activity.htm&type=5) has the following excerpt "Add a Keyword - A piece of text metadata that is passed through with the email for use in Analytics and tracking.", but I didn't find keyword information when looking at the email headers.

Does anyone know how to get this keyword data? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't appear it is accessible anywhere:

Here is the [Idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000TuIEQA0) to make it accessible through a personalization string

Here is a similar [question](https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000p9CPQAY) on the community where it also states this isn't accessible anywhere.

If you are looking to pass attributes for an email in UTM stings you could enable Parameter manage and use q of the 5 [Additional Email Attrbiutes](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000353527&type=1&mode=1) fields